# how to find which if statement is met

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following if statement

```
if ( $missCh[0]['type']==4 OR $missCh[1]['type'] == 4 OR $missCh[2]['type'] == 4 ) {
    echo 'go ahead';
}
```

I would like to find out if `$missCh[0]` or `[1]` or `[2]` is meeting the statement so that I can then ask `if($missCh[X]['value]==3)` but I don't know which part of the array holds true.

Answer (score 0):

```
$types = array( $missCh[0]['type'], $missCh[1]['type'], $missCh[2]['type'] );

foreach ( $types as $key => $val ) {
   if ( $val == 4 ) $fours[] = $key;
}

foreach ( $types as $key => $val ) {
   if ( in_array( $key, $fours ) ) continue;
   if ( $val == 3 ) $threes[] = $key;
}

print_r( $fours );
print_r( $threes );
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to find out if $missCh[0] or [1] or [2] is meeting the statement

AS you currently have it, you're not going to be able to manage this within the script as you currently allow the echo to be actioned if ANY of the criteria return TRUE.

If you want to action something based on what a particular array value is individually, you'll need to check each individually and action as appropriate:

```
if($missCh[0]['type']==4)
  {
    //Do something
  }
elseif ($missCh[1]['type']==4)
  {
    //Do something
  }
elseif($missCh[2]['type']==4)
  {
    //Do something
  }
```

If appropriate, your final elseif could be just else, which would then be a catch all if none of the previous checks returned TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

I've isolated the responsibility to check the if in a function. That function echoes "go ahead" and return the index $miss[$i]['type'] which is equals to 4.

```
<?php

  $miss[0]['type'] = 2;
  $miss[1]['type'] = 4;
  $miss[2]['type'] = 5;

function goAhead($miss) {
  for($i=0;$i<=count($miss);$i++) {
    if($miss[$i]['type']==4) {
      echo 'go ahead';
      return $i;
    }
  }
}

$i = goAhead($miss);

echo $i;
```

This solution will work with one or infinite indexes or $miss array. This means that you will never need to refactor this code if $miss array will growth.

Comment: If the array grows, am I not supposed to change `for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++)` to something like `for($i=0;$i<=count($miss);$i++)` ?

Comment: @Ando, if you are worried about that, then why did you initially use 3 comparisons in your if statement?

Comment: @SunnyRGupta I needed three comparisons, yet I saw the answer and I thought I should comment on it because it makes sense and is best to be fixed.